# How to compress a CSV file using play framework?

Tags: scala, gzip, playframework-2.4

I have a CSV file in the local server and i am sending this file in the play response using below code:

```
def index = Action {
  Ok.sendFile(new java.io.File("fileToServe.csv"))
}
```

But the CSV file can be upto **100GB**. So i want to compress this CSV file before sending it to the play application response. In play, i found this [link](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/GzipEncoding) to add filters which responses should be gzipped. I tried with that but having no luck.

How this GzipFilter works:

1. what extension does it give to the file? Is it .zip instead of .csv?
2. Do i need to do anything outside of the link described?

Is there any other approach to compress a CSV file in play framework?

Answer (score 3):

Since you have said that you file could be up to 100GB, there is no way you could handle zipping it in your `filters` or your `controller`. This will simply blow your heap while loading the file into the memory.

You need to save that `csv` to hdd, `zip` it there and then serve the zipped file as a stream!

Answer (score 0):

As answered by **Atais**, large file will simply blow the heap while loading the file into the memory. So i tried to zip a file while writing to it. I simply used below approach to achieve zipping a large file:

```
val fileToServe = TemporaryFile(new File(fileNameWithoutExtension + ".zip"))
val fos = new FileOutputStream(fileToServe.file)
val bos = new BufferedOutputStream(fos)
val zos = new ZipOutputStream(bos)
zos.putNextEntry(new ZipEntry(fileNameWithoutExtension + ".csv"))

/*write data( Don't read all the data at once from database or anywhere) 
  as it will blow up memory for large file*/
zos.write(data.getBytes)

zos.closeEntry()
zos.close()
```